# Hyperlinks in MVC Partial View Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, asp.net-mvc-partialview

For some reason I cannot get hyperlinks to work in my partial views.
This works in the parent view:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">      
       <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
       @Html.Partial("~/Views/_SomePartialView.cshtml")
    </div>
```

But when I move the `<a>` element into the partial view, even if it is the only thing in the partial view, I cannot click on it. It renders in the source code, but it is not clickable as if there is another element overlayed.

I am assuming that I am not fully understanding the functionality of partial views.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the difference between the generated HTML between the two cases?

Comment: Looking at the source, there is no difference. 
I think the error may be simply malformed HTML somewhere in my layout or other partial views. 
the parent view is simply a few div's with partial views nested inside.
I will remove all partial views except for one and insert only a link in that partial view to see if it resolves the issue.
I will update you shortly.

Comment: If the *rendered* HTML is identical, then something is very fishy. :) I don't mean your source files, but what's actually meeting the browser.

Comment: That solved the issue, so there is malformed HTML somewhere. I'm guessing that it is rendering differently in the page life cycle some how placing it after the malformed HTML while in the Partial View, but before the malformed HTML while outside the Partial View.
Regardless, it is still a "DOH!!" moment.

Comment: An unclosed HTML tag in an unrelated preceding partial perhaps? Either way, glad you're not blaming partial views any more. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not an issue with the Partial Views, rather malformed "bootstrap" elements. I Added a new column when I should have added a new row, thus throwing off the HTML and breaking the hyperlinks.

As for my troubleshooting stated above, I must have placed the placed the `<a href="google.com>google</a>` prior to the malformed "bootstrap" element.